# How to fix : [reduce() takes at most 5 arguments (6 given) ] this error while chunking?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, chunking

I am working on Resume parser application in NLP .
Hence I need to chunk the data in it.
I am using Spacy module for it.
For that I tried instantiating 
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
After executing above code it gives me error like
"reduce() takes at most 5 arguments (6 given)"

Kindly help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Can you please include more of your relevant code?

Answer (score 1):

This error will fix by restarting your IDE(spyder, Anaconda). Source of [Information](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lmfit-py/yMxQrdbBalQ).